# Get all dirty form fields by table row in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that is rendered inside of an HTML table using AngularJS, similar to:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="inputData" id="inputData" ng-submit="submit()">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Employees</th>
          <th>Head Office</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="company.name" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="company.employees" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="company.headoffice" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Users can edit the values in the form. When the form is submitted, I'd like to get the `$index` of the row(s) that were edited. That way I can access the full row from the model via `$scope.companies[$index]` (which is going to get POSTed to a server).

I know I can check individual fields for the `$dirty` property. But is there a way I can retrieve the row number? Or better yet, a way I can retrieve all fields in the edited rows?

Here's a fiddle where, right now, I'm just highlighting the dirty fields using CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/kzxeL0yw/2/

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this ( using **angular.equals**) :

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.companies = [{
    name: "Infosys Technologies",
    employees: 125000,
    headoffice: "Bangalore"
  }, {
    name: "Cognizant Technologies",
    employees: 100000,
    headoffice: "Bangalore"
  }, {
    name: "Wipro",
    employees: 115000,
    headoffice: "Bangalore"
  }];
  
  $scope.orginalCompanies = angular.copy($scope.companies);
  
  $scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.changedIndex = [];
   if(angular.equals($scope.orginalCompanies, $scope.companies)){
      console.log('NOthing is changed');
    }else{
      angular.forEach($scope.companies, function(value, key) {
            if(!angular.equals(value, $scope.orginalCompanies[key])){
          $scope.changedIndex.push(key);
        }
      });
      console.log("changed Index:=>");
      console.log($scope.changedIndex);
    }
  }
  
}]);
```

```css
input.ng-dirty {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="inputData" id="inputData" ng-submit="submit()">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Name
          </th>
          <th>Employees
          </th>
          <th>Head Office
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="company.name" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="company.employees" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="company.headoffice" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Much appreciated!

Comment: @AndroidNoobie glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `ng-change` directive:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.companies = [{
    name: "Infosys Technologies",
    employees: 125000,
    headoffice: "Bangalore"
  }, {
    name: "Cognizant Technologies",
    employees: 100000,
    headoffice: "Bangalore"
  }, {
    name: "Wipro",
    employees: 115000,
    headoffice: "Bangalore"
  }];

  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.inputData);
  }

  $scope.logs = [];
  $scope.logDirty = function(key, $index) {
    var message = 'company[' + $index + '].' + key + 'is dirty';
    if ($scope.logs.indexOf(message) == -1)
      $scope.logs.push(message);
  }

}]);
```

```css
input.ng-dirty {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="inputData" id="inputData" ng-submit="submit()">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Name
          </th>
          <th>Employees
          </th>
          <th>Head Office
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-init='parentIndex=$index'>
          <td ng-repeat='(key, val) in company'>
            <input ng-change='logDirty(key, parentIndex)' type="text" ng-model="company[key]" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" />
      <ul ng-if='logs.length > 0'>
        <li ng-repeat='log in logs'>{{log}}</li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```